# Write a Shell program to read a 5 digit number from user and find the number of occurrences of second digit of that number

Tags: shell

what's incorrect because it is giving an error

> "./vpl_execution: line 260: [: -lt: unary operator expected"

```
#!/bin/bash
num=16386
n=3
t11=$((10**$n))
t1=$(($num / $t11))
x=10
t2=$(($t1 / $x))
t2=$(($t2 * $x))
d=$(($t1 - $t2))
echo $d
s=0
while [ $i -lt 5 ]
do
    n=$i
    t11=$((10**$n))
    t1=$(($num / $t11))
    x=10
    t2=$(($t1 / $x))
    t2=$(($t2 * $x))
    d1=$(($t1 - $t2))
    if [ $d1 -eq $d ]
    then
        $s=$(( $s+1 ))
    fi
done
echo $s
```

Comment: There is no line 260 in this script

Comment: @AkshatSingh : You don't assign any value to `i`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Variable `i` is not initialized before the `while` loop condition tests it.

Also - as @user1934428 noticed - `$i` is not increased anywhere.

One way to solve both issues:

```
while [[ ${i:=0} -lt 5 ]]; do
    ((i++))
```

Comment: This makes it syntactically correct, but since `i` is not modified afterwards either, it will always be undefined here. Therefore the condition is equivalent to `0 -lt 5`, which will always be true.

Comment: True, did not read the script that far. Updated answer.

Comment: On the risk being nitpicking: (1) Could you also add a `do` after the while? (2) IMHO, the incrementation would be more idiomatically be written as `((i+=1))` (3) The `${i:-0}` does not set the variable `i` - it stays undefined (try it). You would have to do a `${i:=0}`.

Comment: nitpicking: anytime. (2) agreed. (3) true, it works though since `((i+=1))` will change it from unset to 1.